# In R, how do you stack figures made using ggplot2 on top of each other?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have made two figures in ggplot that I now want to stack on top of each other. I can get them to stack using `grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol =1)` function in the `gridExtra` package however, both figures get horizontally stretched out becoming the shape of rectangles. Any idea on how to keep both figures square (x and y-axes the same overall length).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

x1 <- rnorm(20)
y1 <- rnorm(20)
x2 <- rnorm(20)
y2 <- rnorm(20)

dat1 <- data.frame(x1, y1)
dat2 <- data.frame(x2, y2)

p1 <- ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(data = dat2, aes(x=x2, y=y2)) + geom_point()

grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol=1)
```

I have tried adjusting the width by using the `widths` argument but I keep getting the error message `Error in arrangeGrob(...) : length(widths) == ncol is not TRUE`.

```
grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol=1, widths = c(1,1))
```

Comment: When exporting your image have you tried setting the appropriate dimensions? Set it to Height: 700 and Width: 430 and you should see roughly square output.

Answer (score 0):

The patchwork package is built for this.

Plot1 + Plot2 # side by side
Plot1/Plot2 # top over bottom

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of patchwork for arranging plots. You get square plots by setting the dimensions as you export the figure.

```
library(patchwork)
p3 <- p1/p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 1, heights = c(1,1))
ggsave("test.png", p3, width = 10, height = 20, units = c("cm"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses but I actually figured it out using the packages I mentioned. What I had to do was add `theme(aspect.ratio = 1)` to both figures.

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) + geom_point() + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
p2 <- ggplot(data = dat2, aes(x=x2, y=y2)) + geom_point() + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)

grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

x1 <- rnorm(20)
y1 <- rnorm(20)
x2 <- rnorm(20)
y2 <- rnorm(20)

dat1 <- data.frame(x1, y1)
dat2 <- data.frame(x2, y2)

p1 <- ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(data = dat2, aes(x=x2, y=y2)) + geom_point()

grid.arrange(p1,p2, ncol=1, widths = unit(10, c("cm")), heights = c(unit(10, c("cm")), unit(10, c("cm"))))
```

[image]